# After cloning a dropdownlist, disable the previous dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net dropdownlist and a html button.On clicking the button(here named as clone), I am supposed to generate a dropdownlist based on the following scenario.

- i start off with only 1 drop down list (that has 5 options) => 1,2,3,4,5 -> first options is selected by default.I hit the clone button.
- i select option 5 (in select list #2 i.e. the dropdownlist generated after the button click for the first time.)
- I hit clone again-> new list (#3) is added with ONLY options 2,3,4
- i select option 2 (in select list #3)
- I hit clone -> new list (#4) is created with options 3,4
- ..and so on.

**I want to disable previous all instances of the dropdownlists(ddlCityName) once i reach the latest dropdownlist.**

**For example:**

- Once I am on the dropdownlist#2, I need the dropdownlist#1 disabled
- For dropdownlist#3, I need the dropdownlist#1 and dropdownlist#2 disabled
- and so on....

here is the existing code to create dropdownlist dynamically:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Category:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCityName" runat="server" DataTextField="City" DataValueField="City" class="ddlClone"></asp:DropDownList>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="button" id="btnClone" value="Add" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="target">
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btnClone').click(function () {
        //$('#ddlCityName').append('<option selected="ddlClone" value="0">Select City</option>');
        var original = $('select.ddlClone:eq(0)');
        var allSelects = $('select.ddlClone');
        var clone = original.clone();

        $('option', clone).filter(function (i) {
            return allSelects.find('option:selected[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').length;
        }).remove();
        $('#target').append($('<span>').text('Category: '));
        $('#target').append(clone).append('<br /><br /><br />');
    });
</script>
```

Please share your ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append the following code at the end of your btnClone click function.

```
$('.ddlClone').attr('disabled', false);
$('.ddlClone:not(:last)').attr("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("ddlCityName").setAttribute("disabled", "true");
```

Comment: That way, after clicking the clone button, the first one is getting disabled but when i try to do the same with 2nd dropdown list, the 2nd dropdownlist  remains enabled and the third one(which just got created) loads disabled.Anu suggestion?

Comment: It goes by ID so whichever ID is in the quotes is the element that'll get selected. Also if you want to enable a specific one do the same thing but instead of "true" at the end put "false".

Comment: Also if you clone a disabled element, the clone will probably also be disabled.